# Optimize multiple one-variable functions with same variable

Tags: python, function, optimization

I have quite a complicated function based on a table input. The maximum of certain columns are end-results (2 in total). These columns are dependent on eachother and other columns.

I need to iteratively optimize the maximum of multiple columns to specific values, so that none of these column-maxima exceeds the specific value.

**The input table snippet (many rows)**

```
Column A, Column B
542.64, 8.5
540.00, 8.5
541.00, 8.6
654.23, 4.7
```

**Calculations**

```
Column C = c1*((c2+(x*column A)^2) / (c1 + c2))^c3
Column D = Column D[n-1]*(1-c4) + (Column B + Column C)*c4 #Startvalue is given
column E = c5*(x*column A)^c6
Column F = Column F[n-1]*(1-c7) + Column E*c7
Column G = Column D + Column F
```

where c1 to c7 are constants

**Solve for X until all conditions are met, and at least one =< closely approaches to be =:**

```
condition 1 = max(Column D) =< value1
condition 2 = max(Column F) =< value2
condition 3 = max(x*Column A) =< value3
```

**I do not want to use if-else statements like this:**

```
solve x for max(column D) == value1

if condition 2 == True and condition 2 == True:
    return x
else solve x for max(column F) == value2
    if condition 3 == True
        return x
    else solve x for max(column G) == value3
        return x
```

*Note: *Instead of full on column calculations I calculate the end-results of a few columns as lists*

*Note 2: *I use a for-loop because the caculations use the n-1 value (previous row) of itself and/or other columns*

Comment: Look into using numpy.

Comment: Thanks for setting the formatting right. I looked into using a lot of things, but always seem to end up with scipy minimize or root. I'm not super familiair with Python yet either.. Could you send me in the right direction with numpy?